# Can you use unchosen answer selections as "0s" to allow for a repeated factors analysis of variance?

Tags: repeated-measures

Here's the study design:

Participants are asked to select up to three (of 23) potential colors for an emotion. For each color they pick, they indicate on a scale 1-10 about how much they think about that color when they think of that emotion. I would like to use a rmANOVA on color intensities, which essentially means that if they did not choose a color, I am coding it as a color intensity value = 0.

Do you see a problem with turning unchosen colors into values of 0 so that I can use a rmANOVA to compare whether color intensities are statistically different across the emotions? If so, is there a better way (turning intensities into percentages based on the number of times the color was ever selected by the participant?). I don't want to loose the repeated element of the design, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

N.B. The term is "significantly different", not "statistically different".

> Do you see a problem with turning unchosen colors into values of 0

Yes: subjects who had been forced to select such a color might have chosen a value other than 0.

> If so, is there a better way

Yes. You haven't described the complete design of your study nor the sample size, but perhaps a mixed model with a fixed effect for each combination of color and emotion, and a random intercept for each subject, would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Kodiologist! In another section of the survey, participants do complete a forced choice question (which limits their response) to one unique color per emotion. I've analyzed that data separately using GOF Chi squares. I have 76 participants.

Comment: @JenniferFugate That's not a complete description of the design of the study.